# How do I resolve a SOAPFaultException with Hostnameverifier socket reset for TTL error message?

Tags: java, soap, ssl-certificate, cxf, soap-client

I have successfully built a client and server (Jetty) over localhost.  This means I launched the Jetty server (https://localhost:8444/ws) and ran the client locally on the same machine and the entire handshake process worked perfectly.

When the client and server run on different machines, the following error message is received:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException :  socket reset for TTL
at org.apache.cxf.transport.https.HttpsClient.DefaultHostnameVerifier.verify(DefaultHostnameVerifier.java:98)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.checkURLSpoofing(Https.Client.java:641)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Https.Client.java:573)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
...
```

**Update: ** in response to Stefan D's question below: By separating both the client and server from each other, I mean to simply move the WAR file to another linux host with IP address XXX.YYY.ZZZ.abc and the client to a different linux host with IP address XXX.YYY.ZZZ.def.

Comment: Please explain what means 'as soon as I separate both of them'. Are both componentes are installed on seperate physical/logical machines? Which one reports the error? Have you checked that your certificates are O.K. especially the CN parameter?

Comment: @StefanD., I just added an update to answer your questions.  See above.

Comment: It's never a good idea to turn security checks OFF! So please do not ask for deactivation of hostname verification, instead ask for the right way to get things done. Security is nowadays not a 'nice to have' but a mandatory 'must have'.

Answer (score 0):

TLS compares the hostname given in the URL for connection against the CN in the certificate. A mismatch leads to the error you struggeling on.

To satisfie this requirement, the parameter CN of the subject (owner) in the certificate must exactly match the DNS hostname whitch is configured to the IP address of your server.
I.e. if the machine with IP address XXX.YYY.ZZZ.abc has the DNS name *flintstone* than the CN (which is set during generation of CSR) must be set to *flintstone*. If the DNS name is located in a different zone than the *FQDN* must be used.

The subject (owner) CN of your certificate is *root.localhost*. I presume that this is not the DNS name of the machine. So as explained above the hostname verification fails.

If you create your own certificates than it is possible to use an IP address as CN but for certificates ordered by a trust center it's no more supported. Also you may face the fact that self signed certificates are refused. For this, a lot of tools (freeware/open source and commercial) can be found in the internet.